# How to center a table caption?

Tags: html, css, html-table, center, caption

I have a long caption on a table and want them both aligned to the center of each other.

HTML:

```
<table>
  <caption>This is a very long caption.</caption>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td><td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td><td>4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
caption {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RZyxzg

Comment: you can add `text-align: center` to center horizontally and `vertical-align: middle` to center vertically

Answer (score 2):

use flexbox for that, using `align-items:center`

```css
table {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  border: red solid
}
```

```html
<table>
  <caption>This is a very long caption.</caption>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks. Is it necessary that the table stretched? Preferably, it should just be as wide as the caption.

Answer (score 0):

It already *is*. Use `text-align: center` you can give a *border* and see that a *long* text will extend the whole width of the table. (also see the behaviour when you set `width` to the `table`)

**Note**: This doesn't seem to work in Firefox - the table do not adjust its width like Chrome when using `white-space: nowrap`.

See demo below:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

caption {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <caption>This is a very long caption and even longer</caption>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work at my end. The caption isn't centered over the table. It just extends to the right over the table. (Tested in Firefox.)

Comment: @Daniel you are right, `white-space: nowrap` seems to break the `table` in firefox